# Understanding thread synchronization problem solution

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, operating-system, semaphore

**Problem**

This is from the "Operating Systems" book by William Stallings.

> Assume there are two processes, A and B, each of which consists of a
>   number of concurrent threads. Each thread includes an infinite loop in
>   which a message is exchanged with a thread in the other process. Each
>   message consists of an integer placed in a shared global buffer. There
>   are two requirements:
>
> 1. After a thread A1 of process A makes a message available to some thread B1 in B, A1 can only proceed after it receives a message from
>      B1. Similarly, after B1 makes a message available to A1, it can only
>      proceed after it receives a message from A1.
> 2. Once a thread A1 makes a message available, it must make sure that no other thread in A overwrites the global buffer before the message
>      is retrieved by a thread in B.

**Solution**

The book shows the following solution:

```
semaphore notFull_A = 1, notFull_B = 1;
semaphore notEmpty_A = 0, notEmpty_B = 0;
int buf_a, buf_b;
```

```
thread_A(...)
{
    int var_a;
    ...
    while (true) {
        ...
        var_a = ...;
        semWait(notFull_A);
        buf_a = var_a;
        semSignal(notEmpty_A);
        semWait(notEmpty_B);
        var_a = buf_b;
        semSignal(notFull_B);
        ...
    }
}
```

```
thread_B(...)
{
    int var_b;
    ....
    while (true) {
        ...
        var_b = ...
        semWait(notFull_B);
        buf_b = var_b;
        semSignal(notEmpty_B);
        semWait(notEmpty_A);
        var_b = buf_a;
        semSignal(notFull_A);
        ...
    }
}
```

**Question**

I'm having trouble understanding why this solution is correct. While trying to trace through the possible execution scenarios, I found the following scenario, which doesn't look correct:

[image]

There must be something really basic that I'm missing here.

If that trace is correct, that would mean that thread A2 is able to execute entirely before A1 gets a chance to picks up the value stored in `buf_b` by B1. Besides, it ends with semaphore `notFull_B` at 1 and semaphore `notEmpty_A` at 1, which could allow another thread from B to run entirely, writing another value to `buf_b` before A1 has any chance to pick up the previous one.

Could someone help, please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is correct. The back-and-forth value exchange is between A2 and B1, not between A1 and B1. At the end, A1 is still waiting to receive a value from B1 while A2 is exchanging values with B1 so the question requirements are still valid.

I think your misunderstanding comes from the fact that the question does not say if A1 puts a value and B1 reads it, then the next value B1 puts to the buffer it must be A1 that reads it. In the scenario you gave, A1 puts value, B1 reads it and writes a value, and before A1 can pick that value up A2 comes and reads it because before A1 picked up the value, A2 successfully sent its value to B1.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I agree that it's correct if you consider that, after B1 picks up A1's value, it doesn't need to be A1 that will pick up B1's value. But the problem says: "After a thread A1 of process A makes a message available to some thread B1 in B, A1 can only proceed after it receives a message from B1. Similarly, after B1 makes a message available to A1, it can only proceed after it receives a message from A1." Doesn't this imply that, if A1 sent a message to B1, it must also receive a message from the same B1? Or am I reading this wrongly?

Comment: Just to add more context to my previous comment, the book also makes the following statement about this problem: "Once two threads enter their critical sections, they exchange messages without interference from any other threads. No other thread in A can enter its critical section until the thread in B is completely done with the exchange, and no other thread in B can enter its critical section until the thread in A is completely done with the exchange.".

Comment: From your original description, the trace you gave appears to be possible, and this last statement you said appears to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right and the text book is wrong.  Your textbook problem looks very much like a Remote Procedure Call, which is a message passing paradigm where an actor sends a message to another actor, and is suspended until a reply message is received by the first actor.  While it isn't necessary in the RPC case for the initial receiving actor to be the one that responds; the response has to be coupled in a way that it isn't just some random message arriving.

The protocol you showed doesn't do that; it is just a simple message pass.  There is a runnable implementation below.  It creates N thread pairs, and attempts to transfer from a->b then b->a, and checks that it gets the expected result.  It doesn't.
Little programs are a great way to explore these problems.  If you do it a lot, it is worth learning Promela which is made for modelling these problems.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ISCALE 1000
#define SSCALE 1000
#define MAXT 160

typedef int Sem;
typedef struct Buf Buf;
struct Buf {
    int buf;
    Sem full;
    Sem empty;
};
typedef struct Targ Targ;
struct Targ {
    Buf *From;
    Buf *To;
    int id;
};

static int niter = ISCALE;
static int napt = SSCALE;
static pthread_mutex_t slock;
static pthread_cond_t scond;

static void Wait(Sem *s) {
    assert(pthread_mutex_lock(&slock) == 0);
    while (*s <= 0) {
        assert(pthread_cond_wait(&scond, &slock) == 0);
    }
    *s -= 1;
    assert(pthread_mutex_unlock(&slock) == 0);
}

static void Signal(Sem *s) {
    assert(pthread_mutex_lock(&slock) == 0);
    *s += 1;
    if (*s == 1) {
        assert(pthread_cond_broadcast(&scond) == 0);
    }
    assert(pthread_mutex_unlock(&slock) == 0);
}

static int Tx(Buf *a, int val) {
    Wait(&a->empty);
    a->buf = val;
    Signal(&a->full);
    return 0;
}

static int Rx(Buf *a, int *val) {
    Wait(&a->full);
    *val = a->buf;
    Signal(&a->empty);
    return 0;
}

static void *BufInit(void) {
    Buf *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
    if (a) {
        a->full = 0;
        a->empty = 1;
    }
    return a;
}

static void *Proc(void *p) {
    struct Targ *t = p;
    unsigned s = 0;
    int i;
    int lj = -1, j;
    for (i = t->id; i < t->id+niter; i++) {
        napt && usleep(rand_r(&s) % napt);
        Tx(t->To, i);
        Rx(t->From, &j);
        if (lj != -1 && j != lj+1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Err: base %d cur %d, prev %d, this %d\n",
                t->id, i, lj, j);
            t->id = -1;
            return 0;
        }
        lj = j;
    }
    t->id = i;
    return 0;
}

int main(int ac, char **av) {
    pthread_t t[MAXT];
    void *v[MAXT];
    struct Targ c[MAXT];
    int nt = 16;
    int i, o;
    Buf *A[2];

    if (!(A[0] = BufInit()) || !(A[1] = BufInit())) {
        perror("bufinit");
        exit(1);
    }
    while ((o = getopt(ac, av, "t:n:i:")) != -1) {
        switch (o) {
        case 't':
            nt = strtol(optarg, 0, 0) * 2;
            assert(nt > 0 && nt < MAXT);
            break;
        case 'n': napt = strtol(optarg, 0, 0); break;
        case 'i': niter = strtol(optarg, 0, 0); break;
        default:
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < nt; i++) {
        /* partition the numeric ranges so we get unique messages */
        c[i].id = (i+1) * niter;
        /*
           The two processes are simulated by alternating the buffers between
           even and odd threads here:
        */
        c[i].From = A[(i&1)];
        c[i].To = A[!(i&1)];
    }

    assert(pthread_cond_init(&scond, 0) == 0);
    assert(pthread_mutex_init(&slock, 0) == 0);

    for (i = 0; i < nt; i++) {
        assert(pthread_create(t+i, 0, Proc, c+i) == 0);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < nt; i++) {
        assert(pthread_join(t[i], v+i) == 0);
        printf("%d = %d\n", i, c[i].id);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```